# Error in implementing Kotlin interface with Java: incompatible return type

Tags: java, kotlin, generics, collections, covariance

I try to implement a Kotlin interface in Java, so my interface looks like this:

```
interface KInterface {
    val items: Collection<ItemInterface>
}

interface ItemInterface {
//
}
```

Then, in my Java code I have the following classes:

```
class JavaItemImpl implemets ItemInterface {
//
}

class JavaImpl implements KInterface {
    private List<JavaItemImpl> items;
    
    @Override
    public List<? extends ItemInterface> getItems() {
        return items;
    }
}
```

Kotlin Collection is covariant `public interface Collection<out E> : Iterable<E>`, so I assume that `List<? extends ItemInterface>` would work when implementing a Kotlin interface.
However, this code gives me an error: `'getItems()' in 'JavaImpl' clashes with 'getItems()' in 'KInterface'; attempting to use incompatible return type`.

One workaround is to make `items` in `KInterface` mutable collection and add a type projection, like this:

```
    val items: MutableCollection<out ItemInterface>
```

But I'd like to know, is there any other way to implement such Kotlin interface, without making Kotlin collection mutable?

Comment: I don't think this is possible because Java lacks Immutable collections and the `Collection` you are using is Kotlin only.  Perhaps there's a java-first immutable collection you could use (Apache Commons Collections??)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Apply `@JvmWildcard`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#variant-generics) to the type parameter of `Collection`:

```
interface KInterface {
    val items: Collection<@JvmWildcard ItemInterface>
}
```

Then the implementation can return `java.util.Collection<? extends ItemInterface>` (or narrow to `List`, as you have):

```java
@Override @NotNull public Collection<? extends ItemInterface> getItems() {
    return items;
}
```